# libssl3 >= 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.2 required but only 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.1 is available on the internet and installed

Tags: apt, package-management

I was trying to build xmrig from source and tried to install the following dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential cmake libuv1-dev libssl-dev libhwloc-dev
```

after that I get error messages saying packages could not be installed due to broken dependencies

```
openssl : Depends: libssl3 (>= 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.2) but 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
```

I am unable to find this version of libssl3 anywhere

on running `sudo apt install -f`, it says it will remove a bunch of programs making upto 700mb, including my browser. Some of them include important packages like ubuntu-desktop.

Please help. I am unable to install any other software as the package management system is now broken.

Comment: have you run `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade` recently?  Its likely *there* but your system isnt up to date.

Comment: I regularly update and upgrade

Comment: I'd suggest running `apt update` as already suggested; as the 1.2 package was replaced by `libssl3 | 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.4 | jammy-updates  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x`  (ie. your software lists appear outdated!)

Comment: Ran the update and upgrade commands again, no change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered this exact problem, but for `libssl-dev` (depending on `libssl3`), and this is on a fresh system which does nothing other than `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade && apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`.  My apt sources follow jammy, jammy-updates, and jammy-security.

I had no problem with this same process literally less than 12 hours ago.  I went digging through commits and found this wonderful clusterfuck:

- jammy-security: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/3.0.2-0ubuntu1.1
- jammy-proposed: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/3.0.2-0ubuntu1.4
- jammy-updates: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/3.0.2-0ubuntu1.4 (same link as jammy-proposed)

If you look closely at the last link, you can see that someone started fooling around with this 8 hours ago, which is why I didn't notice it super early this morning but do now.

I strongly suspect that either a) someone at Canonical broke this, or b) the package servers have not gotten all of their updates in order yet.  Simon Chopin is likely on the hook for this, *if* it's an individual who broke it.

I'm just going to wait it out for 24 hours. If the situation hasn't improved by then, I'll be opening a ticket with Canonical (assuming someone hasn't opened a ticket by then).  It is clearly a dependency version-locking problem somewhere in the dependency tree.

Edit: guiverc is correct, 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.4 is what is "the latest" (what happened to 1.2 and 1.3? yikes), but the entire package infrastructure is not 100% aware of that change yet.  So we're back to my above paragraph, last line.

Comment: As expected, others have begun to report this breakage: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-8.0/+bug/1979244

Comment: What is the prognosis on this ? Do I just wait until canonical sorts this out ?

Comment: @ChaitanyaGambali No other choice.

Comment: @ChaitanyaGambali It's fixed.

Comment: It's fixed in the sense that a completely unrelated OpenSSL CVE got patched and the libssl3 package updated to 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.5, which in essence "solved" the problem described here. I am sure this type of problem will happen again in the future due to Canonical's decision to implement A/B testing on their package servers (re: "phased updates"). But, for today, things are functional again.

Comment: Things are back to normal again ! Thanks @koitsu
A simple apt install -f fixed things